# Finding the Quadratic Form of the Difference of Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

So I got this problem for homework and was able to finish part a where I need to draw an eigenvector on a level curve but I can't solve part b

I'm assuming I need to separate it into $qA(v_1)-qA(v_2)$, but I don't know how to find the difference without the eigenvector or the matrix $A$. Do I need to use the diagonalization formula? If so, how can I use it in this case?

"Assume that the graph below represents the level curves of the function $qA(x, y)$
for some $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$. Assume moreover that $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = −2$ and $\lambda_2  = −3$.

A) On the graph below draw an eigenvector $v_2$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_2  = −3$.

[Here's the graph I drew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WW4EE.png)

[image]

B) Let $v_1$ be length $2$ eigenvector of $A$ with corresponding eigenvalue $−2$, and $v_2$ be
length $3$ eigenvector of $A$ with corresponding eigenvalue $−3$. Find the value of
$qA (v_1-v_2)"$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).